# MeteorJS App not working correctly after *.meteor.com deploy

Tags: javascript, deployment, meteor

I've recently finished up a project in meteor for a contest, and am having trouble deploying to *.meteor.com.

The deploy itself works, as you can see [here](http://powp3.meteor.com), but neither my dynamic templates on the home page that should show posts appear/work, nor can you create an account, etc. I believe I may have an issue with my routing.

I believe this may be a routing issue. I'm using version 0.9.1. The source code can be found [here.](https://github.com/CraftyDevon/peralta)

Any thoughts? Running locally it works great, and deploying with the --debug features doesn't help. No errors are present in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be coming from your links to external scripts in your head tag. These should instead be loaded through a package.

Visiting your site my console reads:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
http://use.typekit.net/c/765ffa/azo-sans-web:i4:i7:n4:n7:n9,proxima-nova:i4…a7a4dd7b8a278a2bbbafab3833d56270f9b83c60ccd331a8fd4b7d3712346dcd4c9f5ac346
```

That is coming from these scripts in your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/mkh6uio.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

See if loading them through a package corrects things.